# Generate new $index for array items per specific key:value in Angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, indexing, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please be patient if I don't understand something and need clarification as I'm still new to Angular, and please simplify explanations for an Angular newbie if you can, thanks!

I am working on a table display of data drawn from a database and using ng-repeat to generate it as something like "item in results.items".  There are three "types" of item, let's just call them "title", "action" and "comment".  Since results.items is the array, the `$index` goes by item placement in the whole array regardless of type.

What I want to do is be able to number only ONE type of item, `item.type=='action'`.  Obviously if I just put 
`<td ng-show="item.type=='action'">{{$index}}</td>` 
it is going to go by the original array index, so instead of having my data with each 'action' numbered 1, 2, 3, etc. in sequence, I end up with them numbered as they fall in the array, something like: 5, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 22.

Can anyone clue me in on a straightforward way to set up the generation of a new `$index` (such as `'$actionIndex'`) in my controller that will re-index only the items that are of type=='action'?  Ideally I'd like to be able to designate a `$scope` function for this in my controller and then just call it with ng-model or something.

I know this inquiry is lacking in the code sampling department -- it's a little awkward in this case for me because I'm still pretty new to Angular and I can't just copy the actual code due to company NDA rules.  Thanks for bearing with me and any assistance you can lend.

**EDIT/UPDATE:** 
After reviewing the solution offered by pixelbits, I am wondering whether what I should do here instead is create a new associated id # for each item where `"type==action"` and just increment it with each successive item where `"type==action"`?

I don't want to filter items with `"type!=action"` out of the display entirely. Right now it is using an inclusive `ng-repeat` and sorting so that other types of "item", where applicable, appear in proper order under this type (`item==action`) to explain/enhance it.  This means I have `<tr>` set up with the `ng-repeat="item in items"` and then `<span>` tags within the `td` cells per row to `ng-show` depending on `type`. I'm not seeing how to logically use a different `ng-repeat` based on `type`.  I just want to reindex all `type==action` items and display that new index numeral instead of that of the larger default array "`items`" itself.

Still working on it ...

Here is a code snippet from the template to illustrate:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{title: item.type=='title', action: item.type=='action', comment: item.type=='comment'}">
    <td class="grid-2">
        <span ng-show="item.type=='action'">{{$index}}</span>
        <span ng-show="item.type!='action'"> </span>                                                    
    </td>
    <td class="action-text grid-8">
        <span class="title regular-item" ng-show="item.type=='title'">
        <h3>{{item.field}}</h3>
        </span>
        <span class="action regular-item" ng-show="item.type=='action'">{{item.field}}</span>
        <span class="comment" ng-show="item.type=='comment'"><i>Comment by:&nbsp;{{item.author}}<br />{{item.field}}</i></span>
    </td>

    <td class="grid-2">
        <span ng-show="item.type=='action'" class="timestamp" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="{{item._created | date: 'hh:mm:ss a'}}">{{item._created | date: 'hh:mm:ss a'}}</span>
        <span ng-show="item.type!='action'">&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

So as you can see I have the general ng-repeat and then the template lays it out according to type.  "Action" is a pretty "important" type as it has special displays the others do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessfully trying what pixelbits suggested here, in the end I went back to the Service and plugged in a counter there which I could place in my template.

Relevant snippet:

```
    }, function(response) {
        var items = response.data;
        var i = 1;
        _.each(items, function(item) {
            if (item.type == 'action') {
                item.counter = i++;
            }
        });
        callback(response.data);
    });
```

And in the template:

```
<span ng-show="item.type=='action'">{{item.counter}}.</span>
```

One of my constant issues is "over-thinking" a problem (making it more complicated in my mind than it needs to be) and this was no exception! Hopefully this will help someone else in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a $watch handler:

**JS**

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.result = ...;
    $scope.actionList = [];
    $scope.$watchCollection('result.items', function(newArr) { 
         $scope.actionList = $filter('filter')(newArr, { type: 'action' }, true);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in actionList">{{ $index }}</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: When I tried the method you suggested, pixelbits, what happened was I got a dump of all numbers from 0 to X representing the total number of items with type "action".  So on lists where five items had the type "action" the {{$index}} var spat out "0 1 2 3 4".  On lists where twenty items had the type "action", well as you can imagine, it came out like this: "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19".

Still looking for a solution ...